# Огибающая - получить прямоугольный импульс огибающий синусоиду

Tags: c++, обработка-сигналов

есть оцифрованный сигнал вот такого вида
[image: график сигнала]

требуется получить график огибающей.

Т.е. получить график прямоугольного импульса.
Цель найти длительность импульса - не одной полуволны, а именно всего импульса.

Как это сделать?

Comment: А где ваш код? Хоть какие-то попытки?

Comment: не ну если автору непонятно, как считать, то чего и пытаться то ... Только тут метку надо ставить DSP, а не qt5

Comment: Попробуйте для начала сделать преобразование Гильберта и от него получить абсолютное значение, то есть в показательную форму перевести. Если бы это был синус, то 100% помогло бы

Comment: подразумевая, что «оцифрованный сигнал» приходит в PCM-виде, то первое, что приходит в голову — взять пороговое напряжение и пороговую длительность, а затем пройтись по данным, ища участки, где сигнал не пересекает пороговое напряжение в течении времени дольше, чем пороговая длительность... ещё можно заменить данные на скользящее среднее... но вопросу не хватает примера входных и выходных данных и желательно с допустимыми погрешностями...

Comment: Ещё можно погуглить на тему "поиск локальных максимумов"

Comment: Отфильтровать высокие частоты - а, вообще мало данных

Comment: [Отфильтровать высокие частоты] Золотые слова. Надо пропустить этот сигнал через цифровой ФНЧ и на выходе получите огибающую. Цифровой ФНЧ можно сделать в каком-нибудь матлабе, он же сгенерирует и Си-код этого фильтра. Подобрать частоту среза ФНЧ и вперед.

Comment: @PavelGridin [не ну если автору непонятно, как считать, то чего и пытаться то ...] не надо "гнуть пальцы"  - "мы все учились понемногу..." Давайте по делу.

Comment: не надо "гнуть пальцы" - "мы все учились понемногу..." - Вы бы дали больше данных о сигнале, чем на картинке. Ощущение, что у вас несущая частота постоянна, если это так, то умножаете на sin(wt) и после обычным фильтром первого порядка выделяете Вашу огибающую.

Comment: @КонстантинФомин до qt надо разобраться в алгоритме, тогда и какой-то код появится(пускай даже не на qt), кстати минусовал не я, елси что:)

Comment: вопрос решен с помощью фильтра низких частот полученного(код)  при помощи http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~fisher/mkfilter

Answer (score 2):

Если примерно известен период полуволн, то можно брать скользящий максимум.

То есть вы проходитесь окном, размер которого не меньше периода полуволны, и для каждого положения окна берёте максимум внутри этого окна.

Началом большого импульса считать правую границу окна, для которого появляется значение выше какого-то небольшого порога. Концом большого импульса считать левую границу окна, для которого значение обратно падает ниже этого порога.